# Can not access a file in a lxd container shared from the host

Tags: chown, lxd

I have an `lxd` container, that is named `master`. I found out that it's root can be found at:

```
/var/lib/lxd/containers/master/rootfs/home/ubuntu/
```

So, I transferred my folder, `tars` to this address. Note that `tars` has two files.

Now, I know that the user id and the group id of `tars` is `root`. On the other hand, the user id and group id of every other file in the container is `166536`.

So, for the folder and the files, I did `sudo chown 166536 <file/folder name>`, to change the user id, and `sudo chown :166536 <file/folder name>`, to change the group id.

Once, I did this, I expected `tars` to be accessible from the container `master`, but that didn't happen. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

---

Here is a method, I found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/4syex0/how_do_you_share_a_folder_writable_in_lxd_host/d5ekota?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x):

> Yeah this was the answer, running with unprivileged container you are
>   not able to see the permissions on the LXD Host, so it appears as
>   Nobody:Nobody. In a way is silly because you can mount the folder into
>   the Container and see the files on it..
>
> For future reference, for anyone having this issue, this are the steps
>   i made (it may not be the correct ones but it works)
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir /tmp/share
> adduser subsonic --shell=/bin/false --no-create-home --system --group --uid 6000 (this is a "service account")
> sudo chown -R subsonic: /tmp/share
> lxc exec Test -- /bin/bash
> mkdir /mnt/share
> adduser subsonic --shell=/bin/false --no-create-home --system --group --uid 6000 (important that the uid is the same)
> exit
> lxc stop Test
> lxc config edit Test (add the line security.privileged: "true" right bellow config: save and exit)
> lxc start Test
> lxc config device add MyMusic MyLibrary disk source=/tmp/share path=/mnt/share
> lxc exec Test -- /bin/bash
> ls /mnt/share/ (note that the subsonic user is there)
> exit
> ```
>
> It's a shame that i couldnt find a way to map the user inside the
>   unprivileged container. if Anyone know's let me know.

Basically, to create a common user, for both the host and the container. Is there anything better that this method available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the container and do

```
whoami
```

You'll get the result:

```
root
```

So, the current user is `root`, and not `ubuntu`. That being said, the address where I was sending the folder to, is wrong. The current address is `var/lib/lxd/containers/master/root/`. Once the folder is sent, check the uid/gid (something like 165536). Change the uid by:

```
sudo chmod 165536 <folder-name>
```

and gid by:

```
sudo chmod :165536 <folder-name>
```

Once that is done, we're sure that the container user `root` will be able to access these files.

Or in a single step `sudo chmod 165536:165536 <folder-name>`.